# Как отобразить список задач с использованием WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Макет контрола выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем временной промежуток, в таблице отображаются задачи запланированные на это время.
С бизнес-логикой все ясно. Проблема с отображением данных.
Ясно, что должен быть какой-то `DataGrid` с автоматической генерацией столбцов. Он привязан к какому-то объекту, у которого...
Если столбец - это поле объекта, то, в зависимости от промежутка дат, количество полей должно меняться. Можно использовать `DataTable`, но возникает проблема с хранением пользовательских объектов и привязкой к их свойствам.
Может у кого-то была похожая задача?

Comment: Ищите "Диагра́мма Га́нта" для WPF.

Comment: Покажите свою VM. Исходя из неё, не стоит мучиться и пытаться запихнуть логику в DataGrid, надеясь сэкономить полторы строчки кода на автогенерации. Генерируйте наполнение View самостоятельно, например на основе `Grid`, вычисляя вручную количество строк/столбцов.